# TRPC doesn't react to config / variables passed (e.g.: enabled : false)

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, react-query, trpc.io

New to trpc and am trying to understand how to use `useQuery` (which I am familiar with from react-query):

```
const IndexPage = () => {

  const { isLoading, data, isIdle } = trpc.useQuery([
    "subscriber.add",
    { email: "elsa@prisma.io" },
    {
      enabled: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnmount: false,
      refetchOnReconnect: false,
      retry: false,
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, //24h
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(isIdle)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

It does hit the endpoint and works fine, but it doesn't seem to take in any of the config options. So even though `enabled` is false, it still hits the endpoint on load and even though `refetchOnWindowFocus` is `false`, it will refetch on re-focus.

Not sure why ?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out: The options / config comes after the square brackets, not inside them:

```
  const { isLoading, data, isIdle } = trpc.useQuery([
    "subscriber.add",
    { email: "elsa@prisma.io" }], <======= closing the square brackets here
    {
      enabled: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnmount: false,
      refetchOnReconnect: false,
      retry: false,
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, //24h
    },
  );
```